# React Navigation: How To Pass props and Navigate to Other Screen onPressing TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I`m trying to build a Contact App using React native. I want to pass the phone number and name to another Screen onPressing each  of them from Contact list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reviewing the [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) Docs:

```
<Button
      title="Details"
      onPress={() => {
        /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
          1stParamData: 'anything you want here',
          2ndParamData: 'anything you want here',
        });
      }}
    />
```

Then in your navigated Screen:

```
const data= this.props.navigation.getParam('1stParamData', 'NO-ID'); 
//NO-ID is a fallback when there's no data.
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 as the other answer didn't work for me (for the reading part) .. this is how it should be:

```
onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
        }}
```

and in the navigated screen:

```
const { itemId, otherParam } = this.props.route.params;
```